# Variable scope; var undefined or same var loop

Tags: javascript

```
Meteor.methods({
      'list.messages' () {
        getTwilioMessages(function(err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.warn("There was an error getting data from twilio", err);
            return
          }
          data.messages.forEach(function(message) {
            if (SMS.find({
                sid: message.sid
              }).count() > 0) {
              return;
            }
            var image;
            if (message.numMedia > 0) {
              var images = [];
              Meteor.wrapAsync(client.messages(message.sid).media.list(function(err, data) {
                console.log(data)
                if (err) throw err;
                Meteor.wrapAsync(data.media_list.forEach(function(media, index) {
                  mediaImage = (function() {
                    let mediaImg = 'http://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + media.account_sid + '/Messages/' + media.parent_sid + '/Media/' + media.sid;
                    return mediaImg
                  });
                }));
                images.push(mediaImage());
                console.log("Just One:" + mediaImage())
                console.log("IMAGESSSS " + mediaImage())
              }));
              message.image = mediaImage();
              console.log("test" + image)
            } else {
              message.image = null
            }
            if (message.from === Meteor.settings.TWILIO.FROM) {
              message.type = "outgoing";
            } else {
              message.type = "incoming";
            }
            SMS.insert(message)
          });
        });
        getTwilioMessages();
        Meteor.setInterval(getTwilioMessages, 60000);
        //   client.calls.get(function(err, response) {
        //     response.calls.forEach(function(call) {
        //         console.log('Received call from: ' + call.from);
        //         console.log('Call duration (in seconds): ' + call.duration);
        //     });
        // });
      },
```

I expect to see different image URL's in the data.media_list.forEach. But, it returns the same image. In the console I get the desired results.

I want these results:

```
message.image = 'http://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/3039030393/Messages/303030/media/3kddkdd'
message.image = 'http://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/3039sdfa393/Messages/303030/media/3asdfdfsa' inserted into the correct message.
```

> instead I get the same URl over and over resulting in the same image
>   for all my messages. I guess my scope is incorrect, but I have
>   attempted to follow: [2ality guide on scoping](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html) and [Explaining
>   JavaScript Scope And Closures](https://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) with no luck.

Comment: I just formatted your code for you. For future reference, you should really have your code formatted anyway as it helps you debug and no one on Stack Overflow wants to read a badly formatted question. Properly formatted code greatly improves your chances of getting a good answer :)

Comment: You do not declare *mediaImage* so it becomes a global variable at the first assignment and at the end you just get the last value assigned. Also, wrapping the assigned function expression in brackets does nothing useful.

Comment: You do declare `var image;` but never use it?

Comment: Just to be clear, there is `let mediaImage` inside the function expression, but it's the outer *mediaImage* that is used for `images.push(mediaImage())` *et al*.

Comment: @RobG I agree it does nothing useful. If I delcare mediaImage I get undefined.

Comment: I've have tried for about 3 days to get this working. Any additional tips would be of great help.